# How to calculate flow rate from given stream function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

I am stuck on a homework question, all because I dozed off in class.

I understand what a stream function is but I don't know how to apply it to calculate the flow in pretty much anything.

Here's the problem I am stuck on. I choose to not give out the question in it's entirety.

> An incompressible stream function is given by $\psi (x,y)$  .Use the stream function to find the volume flow passing through the rectangular surface whose corners are defined by (x,y,z)=(2L,0,0),(2L,0,b),(0,L,b) and (0,L,0).

**My Doubt**
Where do I apply the stream function, at the corners of the rectangular surface or the midpoints? Or am I going in the wrong direction?

Comment: How do you obtain a flow rate from a velocity function? How do you obtain a velocity function from a stream function?

Comment: @Bernhard Velocity times unit area should give out the volume rate, but one has to find the gradient of the stream function to find the velocity components of the field right?

Comment: True, what if the velocity is not constant along the area?

Answer (score 1):

The [*Curl*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_%28mathematics%29) of the [stream function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function) will give the velocity field of the fluid. Integrate this velocity field over the given area to get the volume flow rate required.